# Python module discovery

Tags: python

**Background**: I’m trying to fine-tune our coverage metrics. With lots of developers it often happens that a new sub-module is committed which is not used (e.g. committing a new module which will be used in production code later). As most of the times these are sub-modules, if the module’s members are never called, `coverage.py` will have no knowledge about them, giving false coverage reports. Clearly, I cannot depend on the developers to add such modules in the `.pylintrc` file, so the best way would be to generate a tree of all available python sub-modules under a list of top-level ones. I need something like

```
module_list = ('module_a', 'module_b',)
for module_name in module_list:
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    module_tree = get_submodules(module)
```

And here I expect something like this:

```
{
    'module_a': {
        'module': <module 'module_a' from …>,
        'submodules': {
            'module_a.submodule1': {
                'module': <module 'module_a.submodule1' from …>,
                'submodules': {}
             },
             'module_a.submodule2': {
…
```

Is it possible without tampering with directory paths?